# Meaning and translation　お納めになられる

Tags: grammar, translation

Tell me please, what is the meaning of お納めになられる　in the following sentence.
[image]

Is it just passive ? 
Thanks for help!

Comment: I might be misreading this but I don't see it as honorific. Looks like she's telling お兄さん to tell the landlord/manager/whatever that the rent will be paid

Comment: @ssb You are right, I should have read it more carefully.

Comment: I'm not really sure since it ends with that ようにと... like technically she's saying that the landlord should pay the rent, I guess? @DarkAkira does the landlord paying the rent make sense in the context of this story? If that's the case then the なられる *is* honorific.

Comment: Ok the more I go over this the more I'm convinced that there's just something wrong with it. Either it's a mistake or we're missing context or I'm making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I think that this girl payed/want to pay the rent, while landlord telling her that she shouldn't. But she doesn't listen to landlord (and to this boy) saying "dakara semete..."(first sentence on picture).

Comment: The first 納める (in 家賃くらいは納めさせていただかないと・・) is "to pay" (no.3) and the second one (in ちゃんとお納めになられるよう..) is "to receive, take, 受領する" (no.2 → http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/30841/m0u/)

Comment: If that's the case then my answer is wrong after all.. but is it ok to use なられる like that? Why isn't it お納めになるように if they are telling him to accept the money?

Comment: @ssb　お納めくださるよう(にと)~~お伝えください or お納めいただくよう(にと)~~お伝えください sound politer to me... お納めになられるよう looks like 二重敬語 (but I don't know much about 二重敬語... Maybe お納めになるよう is more natural...)

Comment: Yes yes 二重敬語 is a new word for me. I knew it looked wrong but I couldn't say what it was. The conclusion I arrived at in my deleted answer was that it should be お納めになる but I missed that second definition.

Comment: @Chocolate and sorry for always forgetting @ marks! すいませ～ん

Comment: I agree that it seems like `二重敬語` (which is grammatically incorrect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 納める in どうか管理人さんにちゃんとお納めになられるようにと... means "to receive, take, accept, [受領]{じゅりょう}する, [受]{う}け[取]{と}る, [受納]{じゅのう}する" (No.2 in http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/30841/m0u/ ). I think お納めになられる (お納めになる+れる) is what is called [二重敬語]{にじゅうけいご}("double honorific"?), and according to this page http://wol.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/topics/20100507/106978/?P=2 お納めになる / 納められる seem to be more appropriate. I think お納めくださる or お納めいただく would sound a bit politer.

Comment: 「にじゅうけいご」が「にじゅうひてい」になってもうとるやんけ

Comment: ああ　ほんまや！wwwwwwwww